# Carbon monoxide detector reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

I have recently bought a carbon monoxide spot detector which is not working the way I intended for it. A carbon monoxide spot detector is an analog carbon-monoxide detecting patch that changes color when it comes in contact with carbon monoxide. The problem is that it changes back to it's original color whenever the carbon monoxide leaves the room.

I'd wish for it to stay the same color it changed to after it came into contact with carbon monoxide. What should the reaction look like to fix this problem? I have copy/pasted a scholarly paper from Google to better explain what's happening inside of the patch:

> **Principle of the $\ce{CO}$ – Detector:** The palladium (II) chloride inside is reduced into metallic palladium when exposed to $\ce{CO}$. While the $\ce{CO}$ – level in air is rising, higher amount of palladium is formed. A color change of the solution from pale yellowish orange to orange or grey is followed.
>   $$\ce{CO + PdCl2.2H2O → CO2 + Pd + 2HCl + H2}$$
>   Afterwards, when exposing to $\ce{CO}$ – free air, copper (II) chloride oxidizes palladium back into palladium (II) chloride. In addition, copper (II) chloride is reduced to copper (I) chloride. 
>   $$\ce{Pd + 2CuCl2.2H2O → PdCl2.2H2O + Cu2Cl2}$$ 
>   Then, the regeneration of copper (II) chloride occurs. 
>   $$\ce{Cu2Cl2 + 2HCl + H2O + 1/2 O2 → 2CuCl2.2H2O}$$
>   Thus, the solution resumes to its initial state. (the oxygen comes from the surrounding air)

Comment: One of the main characteristics of a detector function is being reversible. In order to prevent the responsible reactions  of colour changing back, you have to keep oxygen away from the detector.

Comment: Use a webcam and program that detects the change of colour and writes a warning? LED, photodetector and some analog circuitry that closes a lid on the reaction, preventing the regeneration?

Comment: I hope this post is for safety reasons and not because you're running some home experiment that will get you killed...

Comment: @Zhe
This question was for a product idea I had that I wanted to conceptualize.  I was trying to make a sticker for hotel rooms, bathrooms, rentalcars, airplane toilets, etc. that changed color permanently when somebody smoked inside this room. In the end I went a different route. I am still very much interested in the solution to the reaction though.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make sure you weren't about to poison yourself by accident....